# View a secured pdf file on Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, evince

I have a pdf document (an electronic transcript from school) which, as the website from which the pdf file was downloaded says, "are certified PDFs that contain a digital signature and other security features", and "utilizes Adobe's secure certified PDF technology and therefore may only be viewed using the free Adobe Reader".

I can open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro on Windows. But I am using Ubuntu only.

I tried to open it in Evince in Ubuntu, but Evince says the file is locked and required a password. Is there a way to view it on Ubuntu?

I printed from Adobe Pro using some pdf printer, and the output pdf file can be viewed in Evince, but has "VOID" added as watermark as well as the text is rasterized (not searchable), which is undesirable.

Thanks.

Comment: You can a ancient version of Adobe Reader for Linux, does that work? If the file is not confidential you could post a link so that we can try instead of guessing :)

Comment: It is confidential...

Comment: Or use wine or VB - is that out of the question? Do you want to use Linux software?

Comment: @Mi, Prefer Linux software.

Comment: I suggest removing all signatures, restrictions etc... AA Pro is capable of tha... but I guess you don't want to do this either

Comment: Adobe Reader [should work under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3156) to some extent if the native 9 version does not - sadly a native Linux app may not be able to do this as Adobe, M$ etc have not so nice habit of using proprietary software methods which only they are allowed to produce. Also, [this](http://www.creativeprogression.com/removing-signatures/) suggests exporting the file as PostScript document (from AR :/ ), which you can read under Linux directly or convert it back to a PDF.

Comment: @Mi: If AA Pro can do that, then I will be able to read it in Ubuntu. Why do I not want to?

Comment: @user:  I prefer not to install AR on Ubuntu

Comment: I don't need to know reason why you don't want to, that's your business :), I was just suggesting this way of dealing with your issue, after those modifications, you will be able to view this PDF without any problem....One time deal in VB.

Comment: Just found [this](https://maba.wordpress.com/2005/05/12/how-to-remove-a-pdf-certificatesignature-that-disallow-any-document-changes/) which suggest using a perl script to remove the signature things - you may be able to do this manually using GHex or similar as well. Other than that, not a clue.... If Adobe Pro can read it, Adobe Pro can read it because because all the proprietary stuff it contains

Comment: If you have Google Chrome, try opening using its plugin. (just another suggestion).

Comment: Or if you know what restrictions, signatures etc. are there, make those changes to some random PDF, which isn't confidential, so we can try to help ;)

Comment: I can read password-protected `.pdf` files with `xpdf -upw xxxxxx file.pdf`. `xpdf` might work for you, or other tools that appear when you do `man -k pdf` and `apt-cache search pdf`